# Python code quits without doing anything

Tags: python, menu, pygame, geany

I have a problem. i am trying to program a menu for a game in python I am making now. But I have a problem. Every time I run the code, the code exits without even doing anything. i went through the code, and see nothing that can cause this. Here is the code:

```
#importing the libraries
import pygame
import sys

WINDOWWIDTH = 640
WINDOWHEIGHT = 480
#colour       R    G    B
WHITE     = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK     = (  0,   0,   0)
RED       = (255,   0,   0)
GREEN     = (  0, 255,   0)
DARKGREEN = (  0, 155,   0)
DARKGREY  = ( 40,  40,  40)
BGCOLOR = BLACK

DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))

def main():
global DISPLAYSURF, BASICFONT

pygame.init()
DISPLAYSURF = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
BASICFONT = pygame.font.Font('DrippingCool.ttf, 18')
pygame.display.set_caption('Badger Defense - Aplha(0.0.1)')

showStartScreen()

#Drawing the screen
DISPLAYSURF.fill(BGCOLOR)
pygame.display.update()

#Drawing the message
def drawPressKeyMsg():
pressKeySurf = BASICFONT.render("Press a key to play...", True, DARKGREY)
pressKeyRect = pressKeySurf.get_rect()
pressKeyRect.topleft = (WINDOWWIDTH - 200, WINDOWHEIGHT - 30)
DISPLAYSURF.blit(pressKeySurf, pressKeyRect)

#Reaction to the message
def checkForKeyPress():
if len(pygame.event.get(QUIT)) > 0:
    terminate()

keyUpEvents = pygame.event.get(KEYUP)
if len(keyUpEvent) == 0:
    return None
if keyUpEvents[0].key == K_SPACE:
    terminate()
return keyUpEvents[0].key

#Showing the start screen
def showStartScreen():
titleFont = pygame.font.Font('DrippingCool.ttf', 100)
titleMain = titleFont.render('Badger Defense', True, WHITE, DARKGREEN)
titleSecond = titleFont.render('Badger Defense', True, GREEN)

degrees1 = 0
degrees2 = 0
while True:
    DISPLAYSURF.fill(BCOLOR)
    rotatedSurf1 = pygame.transform.rotate(titleSurf1, degrees1)
    rotatedRect1 = rotatedSurf1.get_rect()
    rotatedRect1.center = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT / 2)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(rotatedSurf1, rotatedRect1)

    rotatedSurf2 = pygame.transform.rotate(titleSurf2, degrees2)
    rotatedRect2 = rotatedSurf2.get_rect()
    rotatedRect2.center = (WINDOWWIDTH / 2, WINDOWHEIGHT / 2)
    DISPLAYSURF.blit(rotatedSurf2, rotatedRect2)

    drawPressKeyMsg()

    if checkForKeyPress():
        pygame.event.get()
        return
    pygame.display.update()
    degrees1 += 3 #rotate by 3 degrees each frame
    degrees2 += 7 #rotate by 7 degrees each frame

def terminate():
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

I am running Ubuntu 12.04. I wrote the code in Sublime but tried to run it in Geany as well. Both didn't work.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: Are you calling `main`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't seem to have a `if __name__ == '__main__':` section at the bottom of your code, or anything else that would actually run your code. You are defining everything, but nothing runs because you have not told it to run.

Try adding something like this to the bottom of your code:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The StackOverflow question [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) talks about why you would put that in your file.

Comment: `code` if '__name__' == '__main__': main() `code` but it still doesn't work. The main() is on a second line indented. The name and main bot have two down slashes in front and behind them. Now the main() is not defined.

Comment: It should be `code` if __name__ == '__main__'`code` and not `code`if '__name__' == '__main__'`code`